# Forcing a faction to revolt

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I actually want to force a faction to revolt as their demand is instituting a desirable succession law on a kingdom that I would otherwise not be able to institute. What is the best way to get them to revolt ASAP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it was the biggest faction, I realized any action that angered all vassal's would push this faction to an ultimatum (which is what I want) before any other faction, thus I just went over my demesne limit until their ultimatum fired, took the ultimatum, and immediately gave away extra lands before other factions became too powerful.

EDIT: In hindsight, I could have used the Court Jester title as well, which is more or less the point of it.

Comment: I wonder if just doing something to make the faction leader like you less would be effective?

Comment: I didn't do it because I couldn't think of a temporary way to do that (all levies were already raised, I wanted the faction to revolt to change sucession law during war), but now I realize that's exactly the point of the court jester title.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to raise all the troops of the target vassal(s) and let them sit until the vassal(s) rebel.  This is usually used if you just want to remove a leader (of a faction or otherwise) without instigating a full civil-war, but it could be applicable here.

Other things one could try is to revoke the leader's honorary titles or make him or her the court jester.